# NullPointerException with ChrisBanes's ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

Okay, so on his examples, he states that PullToRefreshAttacher should always be created in onCreate.

However, with my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

PagerAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<ImagePanel> mListOfImagePanel = new ArrayList<ImagePanel>();
ArrayList<String> mListOfImagePanelNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView mDrawerList;
ArrayAdapter<String> mDrawerListAdapter;
boolean doOnce = false;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
Flipper mFlip;
PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //DO THESE FIRST
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this); // This line, nullpointerexception
```

However, when I try to attach the PullToRefreshAttacher, it gives me a NullPointerException, so what's the error here?

Here is my logcat:

```
09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jo.universalcomicreader/com.jo.universalcomicreader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.DefaultHeaderTransformer.applyProgressBarColor(DefaultHeaderTransformer.java:229)

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.DefaultHeaderTransformer.onViewCreated(DefaultHeaderTransformer.java:67)

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.PullToRefreshAttacher.<init>(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:178)

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.PullToRefreshAttacher.get(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:105)

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.PullToRefreshAttacher.get(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:90)

09-03 13:04:35.437: E/AndroidRuntime(4435):     at com.jo.universalcomicreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)

09-03 13:04:35.448: E/EmbeddedLogger(619): App crashed! Process: com.jo.universalcomicreader

09-03 13:04:35.448: E/EmbeddedLogger(619): App crashed! Package: com.jo.universalcomicreader v1 (1.0)

09-03 13:04:35.448: E/EmbeddedLogger(619): Application Label: Universal Comic Reader
```

Comment: In case of an exception, _always_ provide Logcat's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
 mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Indeed it was some problem with my library integration.. Thanks!